# how to draw sphere using math/sphere.js in threee.js?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Drawing the sphere with mesh function.

```
function DRAW_SP(x,y,z)
{
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( .02, 100,100 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    sphere.position.set(x,y,z );
    scene.add( sphere );
}
```

its working good , but how to draw the same using Sphere.js, given in three.js/doc under math?

i tried like this

```
var sphere1= new THREE.Sphere(new THREE.Vector3( -l/2, 0, 0 ), 1.0);
scene.add( sphere1);
```

its not working .. can any one give a simple example to use like this?

Answer (score 0):

sphere.js is the mathematically version of a sphere. It doesn't draw anything. It is used for calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quickest way to create a sphere using the SphereGeometry class.  The below html code loads a web page, imports the latest version of Three.js and OrbitControls to render and animate a sphere in a scene.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Three.js Sphere Example</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Create a grid
        var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
        scene.add(gridHelper);

        // Create a sphere
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32); // Radius, widthSegments, heightSegments
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000FF }); // Blue color
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(sphere);

        // Position the camera
        camera.position.z = 5;
        camera.position.y = 5;

        // Add orbit controls
        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.autoRotate = true;
        controls.update();

        // Render the scene
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
            sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).